# Android Transparent png doesn't show as transparent

Tags: android, png, transparency

I'm using an image with transparency as a ImageButton in my Android app - but when it appears on the android screen - it still has a whitish surrounding border.

I even changed the image to one of the template ones supplied and that still is not transparent (although it is in photoshop).
Am a missing some declaration or something ?

I tried in both the emulator and also running on my phone and its still shows as white on the black background.

Cheers

ScottyB

Comment: 8bit with transparency or 24bit+8bit alpha?

Answer (score 2):

The whitish color IS the button part of the image button :)

Use regular Button and set your image as the android:background of it. Don't set any text.